# Something remapped <C-w> in Vim, how do I reclaim it?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, text-editors, gvim

I've been adding a lot of things to my Vim configuration, and apparently one of the plugins I've installed is reclaiming . Whenever I use that key combination, it shows this error: "E784: Cannot close last tab page".

Is there a way to reclaim 's functionality without disabling the plugins? I mainly use it for switching between view panes in a split window.

Answer (score 2):

normal-mode ^W is pretty critical and plugins probably shouldn't remap it, so there might be a bug report to be made to the maintainer of the plugin.

You can do `:map <C-W>` to get a list of mappings for that combo and from there figure out what's mapping ^W.  There may be multiple listings if the combo is mapped differently in different modes (ie insert, normal, visual).

The command `:scriptnames` may be useful to figure out where to find the scripts for the plugins listed by `:map`.

To just unmap it you can do `unmap <C-W>`, which will restore it to its normal functionality.